# How to update root translation using python script in bge?

Tags: game-engine, armature

I am trying to change root translation of armature (loaded by using bvh) using python script in bge but not able to update values.
I tried following

```
bpy.context.scene.frame_set(3)  
bpy.data.objects['walk_turn_180'].pose.bones[0].location = [0, -10, 0]
```

Its not working for me. When I change frame the values are reset to original values.

Another try..

```
scene = bge.logic.getCurrentScene()  
source = scene.objects  
main_arm = source.get('walk_turn_180')  
bpy.context.scene.frame_set(3)  
main_arm.channels[0].location = [0, -10, 0 ] 
main_arm.update()
```

but still no luck.

Is there any best way to do it or am I doing something wrong? 
Also, instead of `bpy.context.scene.frame_set(3)` is there any method to change keframe using bge?

Answer (score 1):

**bpy** is the Blender API. This means you change the object within the Blender scene not the running BGE scene. Do not use it!

The API for the BGE is **bge**. The [armature](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_74_0/bge.types.BL_ArmatureObject.html?highlight=armature#bge.types.BL_ArmatureObject) gives you access to the (bge-) channels too.